# Multiple conditions on rendered attribute

Tags: apex, visualforce, rendered

I need to display text based on record type & has teammember.But it displays both messages regardless of record type.Below is the part of my visualforce page.

```
<apex:outputLabel style="color:red;" 
                  rendered="{!IF(HasTeamMember && ENT_ED_LIHTC__c.recordtype.name =='Standard Deal', false, true)}" >
    Note: At least one Team Member with Role as Originator is required.<br/><br/>
</apex:outputLabel>

<apex:outputLabel style="color:red;" 
                  rendered="{!IF(HasTeamMember && ENT_ED_LIHTC__c.recordtype.name!='Standard Deal', false, true)}" >
    Note: At least one Team Member is required.<br/><br/>
</apex:outputLabel>
```

---

```
public boolean HasTeamMember
{
    get
    {
      ENT_ED_LIHTC__c deal = (ENT_ED_LIHTC__c)ctrl.getRecord();
      List<ENT_Enterprise_Team__c> tmForInsert = new List<ENT_Enterprise_Team__c>();
      list<RecordType> rtype =[Select id,recordtype.name From recordtype where id =:deal.recordtypeid];

        if(TeamMembers.size() > 0)
        {
            for(ENT_Enterprise_Team__c tm : TeamMembers)
            {
                if(tm.User__c != null && tm.Role__c != null && tm.Role__c != ''&& tm.Role__c == 'Originator' && rtype[0].name=='Standard Deal')
                {
                    return true;
                }

                if(tm.User__c != null && tm.Role__c != null && tm.Role__c != '' && rtype[0].name!='Standard Deal')
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code snippet where your variable `HasTeamMember` is calculated? And what do you mean with `Vf page is not displaying.`? You mean output label?

Comment: @mast0r updated the code

Comment: Just as a side note, you really shouldnt mix your logic like this.  You have some logic being performed in the controller, and some on the VF page.  You really should perform all of your logic in the controller and reference that controller property in your VF rendered attribute

Comment: yes outputlabel was not displaying when I pasted the code.How did you do that ?

Comment: You should use `DeveloperName` instead of `Name` when querying the record types.

Answer (score 6):

I've been able to make things like this by simply doing this:

`render="{!HasTeamMeber && ENT_ED_LIHTC__c.recordtype.name =='Standard Deal'}"`

At least it seems to work fine with a page I was working on.

Another way would be to have a Boolean method in your controller that returns true or false and put the logic there.

Answer (score 5):

Generally your code is almost clear. If you can not see labels on the page that means that your formula condition just returns `false`. Try to figure out why it is happening. Make some debug outputs in `HasTeamMember`. Maybe `TeamMembers` size is 0? The simplest thing what you can do is to output these two variables on the visualforce page to check it content:

```
HasTeamMember: {!HasTeamMember} <br/>
Recordtype: {!ENT_ED_LIHTC__c.recordtype.developername}
```

Then you will see what that variables really are.

Some tips to improve your page and controller:

- You dont realy need to use List when querying record type name. You can use this construct: `String rtype =[Select DeveloperName From recordtype                               where id =:deal.recordtypeid].DeveloperName;`
- Use `DeveloperName` instead of `Name` when querying the record types. [DeveloperName](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm) is a unique name of the object in the API and Name is just a label
- As @Dunc44 said pack all of your logic in to the controller. Why don't use `ENT_ED_LIHTC__c.recordtype.name =='XXX'` construct within the `HasTeamMember` method? It's more convenient
- Check variables with `System.debug` outputs or directly on the page to see what they are really doing

I hope it will help you, good luck.